# .htaccess regex for redirect subdomain to root domain & redirect old permalinks

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

ok, i have at site a blog.mysite.com, and recently migrated all content to a new wp install at mysite.com.

i want to redirect all of the posts from blog.mysite.com to mysite.com and also account for permalink structure.

blog.mysite.com is /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

mysite.com is /%category%/%postname%/

the goal is if anyone goes to

blog.mysite.com /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

they will be redirected to

mysite.com is /%category%/%postname%/

i want to ultimately delete all content at blog.mysite.com as well, so i wound want to make this work via .htaccess after it's deleted.

i can't seem to work out exactly how to do this in .htaccess.

also, both sites live in their own directories on the server.

/blog.mysite.com and /mysite.com

thanks so much for your help!

Comment: also, i thought about using (http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) but i think i would need to install it at blog.mysite.com, and if i ultimately want to delete that site, it will be deleted too:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this was the answer via htaccess (to be placed in htaccess within the blog.mysite.com directory).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:blog\.)site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: why was this downvoted?  it is the specific answer to the question i asked.

Answer (score 0):

yes, use the redirection plugin. redirect all traffic from blog.mysite.com to mysite.com and use the plugin for a second redirect to the actual page.

After you moved the site and change the htacess run a crawler on mysite.com and fix the 404 errors that you will see.

Comment: thanks!  i'm looking for an htaccess solution though.